# Python: Sort list using another list order, having different lengths, and without 'sorted'

Tags: python, list, sorting, plone

I'll to explain this right:
I'm in an environment where I can't use python built-in functions (like 'sorted', 'set'), can't declare methods, can't make conditions (if), and can't make loops, except for:

- can call methods (but just one each time, and saving returns on another variable

  foo python:item.sort();  #foo variable takes the value that item.sort() returns

  bar python:foo.index(x);
- and can do list comprehension

  [item['bla'] for item in foo]

...what I don't think that will help on this question

I have a 'correct_order' list, with this values:

```
correct_order = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

and I have a 'messed_order' list, with this values:

```
messed_order = [55, 1, 44, 3, 66, 5, 4, 7, 2, 9, 0, 10, 6, 8]
```

Well, I have to reorder the 'messed_order' list, using the index of 'correct_order' as base. The order of the rest of items not included in correct_order doesn't matter.

Something like this would solve (again, except that I can't use loops):

```
for item in correct_order:
    messed_order[messed_order.index(item)], messed_order[correct_order.index(item)] = messed_order[correct_order.index(item)], messed_order[messed_order.index(item)]
```

And would result on the 'ordered_list' that I want:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 55, 66, 44]
```

So, how can I do this?

For those who know zope/plone, I'm on a skin page (.pt), that doesn't have a helper python script (what I think that is not possible for skin pages, only for browser pages. If it is, show me how and I'll do it).

Comment: You're in one uselessly broken environment.

Comment: Do you work for the Department of Arbitrary Restrictions?

Comment: @Thanatos No, on this specific case I'm limited to use few artifacts. On a "all possible environment", I'd just end with that "for" solution I put on the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to answer, not knowing exactly what's allowed and what's not. But how about this O(N^2) solution?

```
[x for x in correct_order if x in messed_order] + [x for x in messed_order if x not in correct_order]
```

Comment: I'll accept this, as I think anyone post another solution with a reduced cost. My list doesn't have too much items, so, I think I'm okay with this. But I continue looking for better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Script (Python)` object in your skin and use that as a function. TALES expressions are limited for a reason: they are there only to help you create HTML or XML markup, not do full-scale business logic. Better still, create a proper browser view and avoid the severe restrictions laid on Through-The-Web editable code.

Also, you are misrepresenting or misunderstanding TALES. You *can* use builtin methods like sorted and set. And instead of `if` you can use test(condition, iftrue, iffalse) or a good old `condition and iftrue or iffalse` with the limitation that the result of `iftrue` must itself evaluate to true.

Even better, you can access a limited set of Python modules via the `modules` dictionary, such as `modules['string']`. You'll need to make additional security declarations in a filesystem python module to extend this though.

See the [Python TALES expression section](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/AppendixC.html#tales-python-expressions) of the TAL documentation. Note that the list of built-ins accessible to TALES listed there has since been expanded to cover newer python versions.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'll look on docs, and learn more about TALES.

Answer (score 0):

Does the exact order of the 55/66/44 items matter, or do they just need to be listed at the end? If the order doesn't matter you could do this:

```
[i for i in correct_order if i in messed_order] +
    list(set(messed_order) - set(correct_order))
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, doesn't matter. I'll just put Paul solution as he answered earlier (don't be mad with me).

Comment: This solution is not valid as python built-in functions are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that **destroys `messed_order`**

```
[messed_order.remove(i) or i for i in correct_order if i in messed_order] + messed_order
```

This one sorts `messed_order` in place

```
messed_order.sort(key=(correct_order+messed_order).index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to detract from the answers already given, but it's python - you *aren't* arbitrarily restricted from using loops:

```
for item in correct_order: messed_order[messed_order.index(item)], messed_order[correct_order.index(item)] = messed_order[correct_order.index(item)], messed_order[messed_order.index(item)]
```

is as valid as putting the loop on two lines.

Alternatively, this is Zope - if you can't do it in a single "python:" expression, yes you can use a helper script.  Scripts are found by acquisition, so a template containing something like:

```
<tag tal:define="abc context/script">
```

will lookup a *either* an attribute 'script' of the current object (*context*) [which could be a method or a property], or a "Script (Python)" object named *script* in the current folder, or in any ancestor folder! In fact, it doesn't even need to be a script object - though for your purpose it needs to be some object that returns a list.

Far from "the Department of Arbitrary Restrictions" as Thanatos put it, it's more as if there aren't enough restrictions!